# How do I make Richfaces component <rich:fileUpload> be required in form

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

I tried to add a `<rich:fileUpload>` into a richfaces wizard like [this one](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/include.jsf), but when i delete those inputfield (e.g. in step 1), which are required and give error message if not filled, the uploadfield instead is not checked and the wizard switches to the next state

Comment: The fileUpload doesn't work like the other input fields, it's just for uploading files. What do you want to validate?

Comment: i wanted to validate that there is a file set in the upload component but i think i have to use the jsf-apache commons way for that

Answer (score 1):

After the required="true" doesn't work for rich:fileUpload (Richfaces 4), and neither does adding a custom field validator on the rich:fileUpload itself (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-5177), I ended up with adding a separate hidden field and doing the validation on this one to check if files have been uploaded:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="richUpload" fileUploadListener="#{myForm.fileUploadListener}">
    <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="uploadFilesCounter" />
</rich:fileUpload>
<h:inputHidden id="upload" value="#{myForm.uploadFilesCounter}">
    <f:validator validatorId="uploadFilesCounterValidator" />
</h:inputHidden>
```

and in the Managed Bean:

```
public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    this.uploadFilesCounter = uploadFiles.size();
}
```